# Programmatic-ally bind DOM element to $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{foo}}
        <button ng-click="bindToMe" />
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="anotherCtrl">
        {{foo}}
        <button ng-click="noBindToMeInstead" />
    </div>
</div>

<!-- yes its outside of ng-app -->
<div id="tempZone">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo" />
</div>
```

What I would like to do is use the `#tempZone` to compile/data bind as if it was a part of a specific scope.

Something like:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
 myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.foo = "init1";
     $scope.bindToMe = function(){
         var tempZone = document.getElementById('tempZone');
         $scope.$MAGICBINDMETHOD(tempZone);
     };
 });
 myApp.controller('anotherCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.foo = "init2";
     $scope.noBindToMeInstead = function(){
         var tempZone = document.getElementById('tempZone');
         $scope.$MAGICBINDMETHOD(tempZone);
     };
 });
```

I want this so I can write a modal window service that allows for the loaded template to interact with the scope that called the modal. So far I have seen no examples of this working. Is binding an dom element to a scope possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the answer is just extremely simple.

```
 $scope.$MAGICBINDMETHOD(tempZone);
```

is just

```
 $compile(tempZone)($scope);
```

and its done.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a controller and scope for your common `tempZone`, use a service for data sharing (for the input), and $emit a 'bindToMe' event from one controller, to signal the other controller to stop listening to changes.

Something in the lines of

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{foo}}
        <button ng-click="bindToMe()" />
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="anotherCtrl">
        {{foo}}
        <button ng-click="bindToMe()" />
    </div>

<!-- no its not outside of ng-app -->
    <div id="tempZone" ng-controller="tempZoneCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myService.foo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controllers:

```
 angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService){
     $scope.foo = "init1";
     $scope.$root.$on("bindToMe", function(event) {
         if (event.target != $scope) releaseBinding();
     };
     $scope.bindToMe = function(){
         $scope.$emit("bindToMe");
     };
 })
 .controller('anotherCtrl', function($scope, myService){
     $scope.foo = "init2";
     $scope.$root.$on("bindToMe", function(event) {
         if (event.target != $scope) releaseBinding();
     };
     $scope.bindToMe = function(){
         $scope.$emit("bindToMe");
     };
 })
 .controller('tempZoneCtrl', function($scope, myService){
     $scope.$watch('foo', function(newV) { myService.foo = newV; });
 })
 .service('myService', function() {
     return {};
 });
```

Your modal will be independent on any other controller that binds on the values, it just relies on a singleton service (which is in fact the correct tool for data passing).

Also, you'd want to check angular-ui's $dialog provider (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog). They are rewriting the twitter-bootstrap javascript to make it angular-friendly.

Comment: Sorry to add complexity. But I don't necessarily know the name of the variables I am watching for. I am trying to create a generalized service that can bind to any scope and consume any template. +1 for being helpful.